# dotnet dev-certs https --trust not work and return this error "There was an error creating the HTTPS developer certificate."

Tags: .net, ssl, .net-core, dotnet-dev-certs

in windows 10 i want create and run .net core project but before need to trust to certificate by this cli command "dotnet dev-certs https --trust"
when I execute this command return error like this 
"There was an error creating the HTTPS developer certificate."
how can solve this error

Comment: Does it really not give you any more information? Can you try `--verbose` too? If there's still no information you could try running [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if there are any obvious API calls it's making that fail, or looking in the event log in case it puts anything there (but I'd be surprised). Or I expect you can get hold of a dev copy of dotnet to build / step-through / debug yourself, but that's probably not easy to set up so I'd treat that as a last resort. Are you running as a local admin? (I'm not sure if that matters or not)

Comment: are you running with elevated priveleges? (might be needed if it is installing a cert)

Comment: @Rup
I try --verbose and get some information like this

No valid certificates present on this machine. Trying to create one.
Error creating the certificate.
Exception message: The type initializer for 'System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite' threw an exception.
Exception message: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes I have Administrator privelege

Comment: Great, that's an actual error to investigate, e.g. [this old GitHub ticket](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/961). Can you check the CNG Key Isolation service is running in control panel?

Comment: @Rup
CNG Key Isolation service was disabled. I start that and the problem solved.Thank you very much